# Configurable number of Spring DAO objects

Tags: spring, dao

I have an app that access a configurable list of databases.  I do not want to hardcode the corresponding DAO objects in the class.  Is there a way to do that in Spring?

The hardcoded way would be:

databases.properties:

```
db1.url = jdbc://db1.acess.com:3306
...
db2.url = jdbc://db2.access.com:3306
...
db3.url = ldap://ldapdb.access.com:3306
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="MyServicebean" class="com.MyServiceImpl">
    <property name="DBDao1" ref="DBDao1"/>
    <property name="DBDao2" ref="DBDao2"/> 
    <property name="LdapDao" ref="LdapDao"/>
</bean> 

public class MyServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private DBDao DBDao1;

    @Autowired
    private DBDao DBDao2;

    @Autowired
    private LdapDao LdapDao;
...
}
```

Is there a more flexible way of configuring and autowiring DAO objects based on how many DBs we specify in databases.properties?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750079/strategy-for-many-daos-in-spring-java?rq=1. Maybe you should create DAO factory and inject it instead of injecting every DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your *database.properties*, it seems not all DAOs are connecting to Databases. Some are connecting to LDAP server. So obviously implementation of DAOs will be different and can't generalize/abstract it.

If all DAOs that connect to databases perform the same set of operations and connects to different databases based on some criteria (ex: clientId) then take a look at Spring's **AbstractRoutingDataSource**. http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/